# communicate between two java application in a same JVM

Tags: java

What is the best way to communicate between two java applications in a same JVM. I use RMI but I wonder that is there something better of faster or is not?

Comment: Regarding "better": I'd stick with an interface that allows to separate the processes (or even nodes) later on if needed (even if the actual implementation differs between these scenarios). Unless RMI is a performance problem, it's probably not the worst choice.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on two java applications ? Something like two web apps (wars) in same tomcat container ?

Comment: You may check JMS but JMS maybe more conflict for your logic

Comment: Linux uses files, why not write to a file?